# How can I get the full URLs for my SSO service provider end points?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am trying to use https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php to generate metadata manually.

The form needs this: **Attribute Consume Service Endpoint (HTTP-POST)**

But when I start my app, and step through it and get to the `AuthController.cs`

I put a breakpoint here so I can get the **URL** of my Attribute Consume Service Endpoint

```
var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");
```

But it only shows me `/`

How can I get the full URL to the Attribute Consume Service Endpoint (HTTP-POST)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The application generate the SP metadata it selv in the [MetadataController](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/MetadataController.cs).

This also includes adding the [Attribute Consume Service Endpoint](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/MetadataController.cs#L47) to the XML metadata.